# What does this recursive method do?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to figure out what this recursive method does. Can someone please go through couple of steps of the recursive calls? I don't seem to get it.

```
public static int p(int[ ] a){
    if(a.length==0) return 0;
    else if(a.length==1) return a[0] %2;
    else return p(Arrays.copyOfRange(a,0,a.length/2)) + p(Arrays.copyOfRange(a,a.length/2,a.length));
}
```

Comment: Run it manually, by hand for some small arrays - what *is* going on? Note that the recursive call itself simply processing half the array (first, then second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, the two recursive calls apply the function to the first and second half of the array, respectively.

As a second hint, since each call sums the values of the two subcalls, the result will be the sum of the function as applied to each singleton array consisting of a single element.

Finally, the result on a single element is 0 if that element is even and 1 if it's odd.

Given these hints, can you find a simple description of what this method does?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer.  However the true answer to what does this recursive method _really_ do:  Makes me appreciate simple iterative for loops.  :-)

Comment: i guess it prints the numbers of odd numbers in the array. thank u for the help